# How do you get airpods pro to play/pause on macos with single squeeze?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, music, airpods

For some reason I can't get my airpods pro to play/pause with single press on MacOS, only to activate Siri.  In bluetooth settings, I can open the options but they only let me change the function for long press, not short press. Previously I'm sure that play/pause worked fine and I'm not sure what went wrong. It's very annoying to have siri come up when I'm just trying to pause. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot of options missing short press]

Using a 16 in M1 macbook pro, running MacOS Monterey V 12.1 (21C52)

Comment: The ability to play/pause with 1 squeeze is a fixed behavior, that's why you don't see it in settings. It works fine for me on Monterey, but I don't have an M1. Can you try opening the Music app, playing a song on the airpods, then squeezing them once to pause?

Comment: For reference: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212203

Comment: Are you saying that a short single press is activating Siri every time? Can you reproduce this on other devices? Tried unpairing and repairing?

Comment: Same happening here. M1 MB Pro 16" Monterey. Looked everywhere, pressing AirPods Pro during Apple Music play, and in fact everywhere too, opens Siri up. Even changed default Siri preferences, didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

For me this happens when i'm in a Call where my microphone is used.
Tried with Discord, Zoom and Microsoft Teams.
Getting out of the call restores the settings and everything works fine.
It seems during a call the media audio is routed with the call audio but the media controls are not, so the system responds as if there was no media playing.

Comment: I had the Zoom app opened but was not in a call, closing it fixed the issue! Thank you!